# Problems after installing Ubuntu 18.04 and EPS

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu, eps, ghostscript

After installing Ubuntu v. 18.04, I suppose that ghostscript does not work proper. It cannot convert eps-files to pdf. I suppose that the TeX-command epstopdf make use of it. Is that true? What alternative do I have?

I use Ubuntu 18.04
TeXmaker 5.0.2
Ghostscript 9.25

Here an error from the log-file:
!Package pdftex.def Error: File `eps/OM27-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

Beside TeX there is no program at the moment at my computer for viewing EPS-files. Most of those programs make use of ghostscript.

MatCos

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution:
Indeed there were problems with ghostscript, especially 
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles was empty. Instead there was a map 
/usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/. After copying the files to ghostscript, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

After an update ghostscript didn't work at all. Finally I had to remove the files placed in /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles. After doing the installation of texlive and texlive-font-utils there appeared a link from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles to /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/.